How to authorize subscriptions in HotChocolate
How do you do authorization (not authentication) for subscriptions, where some users (but not others) may have access to a topic, and the access may change with time?
For example, I have topics like OrderUpdated_T3JkZXI60UlnflZ where the last part is the order ID. So users can subscribe to updates for individual orders. However: 1) a user may not necessarily have access to an order, and 2) a user that has access, may lose that access due to changes in the order state.
I'd like for ongoing subscriptions to never trigger for users who are no longer authorized for that topic/order. I can find no way of implementing this using HotChocolate. (Ideally I'd also like to fail the initial subscription if the user is not authorized for that topic/order at the time of subscription, but that' not terribly important if I can do the above.)
The closest I can get is to allow all users to subscribe to all topics, but return a null value for the OrderUpdated payload if they are not authorized to view it. However, this still leaks information about orders being updated, even if the order itself is not visible, since the order ID is in the topic name.
If it's relevant, I'm using SSE for subscriptions (to simplify authentication).
